# joining two lists of different sizes to create a new dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, set

I'm attempting to make a deck of cards recursively using symbols and their values, and I can create the code to make one pass through the iteration, but it's not updating to create all 52 cards.
I've tried using different updating methods but their not working correctly due to my coding error.

```
test_values = ["♠", "♣", "♥", "♦"]
test_keys = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']


# Printing original keys-value lists
print ("Original key list is : " + str(test_keys))
print ("Original value list is : " + str(test_values))


new_dict = {}

for key in test_keys:
    for value in test_values:
        res[key] = value
        new_dict = {**new_dict, **res}

# Printing resultant dictionary
print ("Resultant dictionary is : " +  str(res))
print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```py
{'A': '♦', '2': '♦', '3': '♦', '4': '♦', '5': '♦', '6': '♦', '7': '♦', '8': '♦', '9': '♦', '10': '♦', 'J': '♦', 'Q': '♦', 'K': '♦'}
```

Why only the last suit is created?

Comment: what result were you *expecting*? Dictionary keys must be unique... what exactly is this dictionary supposed to be used for anyway? Note, your example isn't complete, since `res` is not defined anywhere

Comment: Yes, I forgot the `res = {}` statement above. My bad. The dictionary is used for a blackjack game I'm making.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a list of all the cards, rather than a dictionary. Here is a way to create a list of tuples:

```py
test_values = ["♠", "♣", "♥", "♦"]
test_keys = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']

# Printing original keys-value lists
print ("Original key list is : " + str(test_keys))
print ("Original value list is : " + str(test_values))

cards = []

for key in test_keys:
    for value in test_values:
        cards.append(key + value)

# Printing resultant list
print(cards)
```

This gives the output:

```py
['A♠', 'A♣', 'A♥', 'A♦', '2♠', '2♣', '2♥', '2♦', '3♠', '3♣', '3♥', '3♦', '4♠', '4♣', '4♥', '4♦', '5♠', '5♣', '5♥', '5♦', '6♠', '6♣', '6♥', '6♦', '7♠', '7♣', '7♥', '7♦', '8♠', '8♣', '8♥', '8♦', '9♠', '9♣', '9♥', '9♦', '10♠', '10♣', '10♥', '10♦', 'J♠', 'J♣', 'J♥', 'J♦', 'Q♠', 'Q♣', 'Q♥', 'Q♦', 'K♠', 'K♣', 'K♥', 'K♦']
```

The reason only the last suit was created in the dictionary in your solution is because dictionary keys can only hold one value. When you mapped A → ♠, this created the dictionary `{'A': '♠'}`. When you then mapped A → ♣, this overwrote the initial value for `'A'`, changing the dictionary to `{'A': '♣'}`.

Comment: Thank you. I had forgotten dictionaries are made this way. I created the cards as you did above by combining the suit+value, yet if I want to be able to add the values, such as with a blackjack game I'm making. I would have to strip off the suit symbol, while making sure to assign a value of **'10'** to the face cards, and also either a **'1'** or an **'11'** to the ace depending on the user's choice.